# Check convergence of discrete random variable in almost sure sense

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Consider the following Sample Space: $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $P(\omega) = 0.25$ for any $\omega \in\Omega$. We
consider the sequence
$X_n(\omega) = \frac{2 \cdot\omega \cdot n + 1}{n + 1}$.

I need to study the convergence of $X_n$ in the a.s., Probability and Distributions sense

Ok so the first step is finding the limit, and that's where I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly.
Do I need to find the expectation of the variable, which will be $\frac{2\omega + 4\omega + 6\omega + 8\omega}{4} = 5$ as n $\to \infty$ ,  or is the limit itself a random variable, with values $\{2,4,6,8\}$ with equal probability?

Comment: $X_n(\omega) \to 2\omega$ for every $\omega$. So the convernce holds in every sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes that was my initial solution, but I thought perhaps I was doing something wrong and I had to find a singular numerical limit. Thank you.